# How to remove erroneous double quote in front of a string

Tags: search, replace

```
cat group.txt

""BASEBALL"
        Flags: E,3
        "Jason" "O"
        "Kim" "T"
        "Eric" "G"
        "Jenny" "B"

"TENNIS"
        "Smith" "O"
        "Turner" "T"

""SOCCER"
        Flags: E,3
        "Hulk" "O"
        "Ironman" "T"
        "Loganoll" "G"
```

I would like to remove the extra double-quote(") from this file using sed (or any other).  Notice BASEBALL and SOCCER have extra double-quote (") in the front of the string.

I tried to use

```
sed 's/^\"\"[a-zA-Z0-9]/\"\$/g' group.txt >> group.txt.dqremoved
```

but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to replace two leading double quotes with one, you don't need anything more complicated than

```
sed 's/^""/"/' group.txt > group.txt.dqremoved
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only the first character per line you could use

```
cut -c 2- file
```

Comment: This would remove the `"` before `TENNIS` too, and move everything left by two character positions.